# How to send the Assersion failure emails and end of test results via email in Jmeter?

Tags: email, jmeter, assertion

[link for jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dVr.png)i am using jmeter for my testing. I am finding it hard to find a way to send an email to my account when an assertion fails. Or when the job is complete, i want the results sent to my email. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an email with JMeter using [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler). Something like:

- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), condition `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==false`

  - SMTP Sampler

See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for details on how to configure SMTP Sampler

Results can be send in the similar way.

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   This is required to configure JMeter to save results into a file as soon as they're available in order to ensure you won't miss a single request results
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan. tearDown Thread group is being executed after all other Thread Groups
3. Add SMTP Sampler as a child of the tearDown Thread Group and configure it to send .jtl results file to the specified email(s)

Comment: I have added a picture above(its a link.) And i am getting 500 error. Can you please check?

Comment: esponse message: Other MessagingException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: www.googlemail.com, port: 587;

Comment: You didn't read the article. Server name needs to be `smtp.gmail.com`. Username needs to be valid Gmail username. https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: I changed accordingly, but am getting this error:            Response message: AuthenticationFailedException: authentication failed - wrong username / password!
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtV
534-5.7.14 Q-oH9bB2mhokallDZkmBBOZ1k1LR8XUGmKfMCh7AyuDOLOye6WQgW03RAOvAmMOmdMZJa9
534-5.7.14 bOIdjHapFp7pMA0C9p5mB-17UdGKYvJAgwJ13ENGuxf0CRFb1dS51rwGEIsdVCKoHuoMs3
534-5.7.14 2QHoEiMGLxYJzku1W6R9o3LahOAZ3-
5

I tried with three differen temilas and correct passwords, but its still failing

Comment: The error states `wrong username / password`. For some reason I trust Google more than you. Discussion is closed

Comment: Ok, i got that thing fixed, thanks for the hep. Now, how to get the correct error message? I want to get the message from the response to my email.    I changed the email to only my user name. username and password instead of username@gmail.com and password

Comment: Yes, now my jmeter is working perfectly. Thank you for the help

Comment: Can you plz tell me, how you have captured failure result & added it as a body of email using SMTP Sampler ?